# PulseAudio Equalizer doesn't survive neither suspend nor hibernate

Tags: suspend, pulseaudio, hibernate

First time Ubuntu boots up it's fine. I can listen to the music and the sound is equalized. Then if I suspend the PC or let it hibernate then, after I have woken it up, the sound becomes plain. If in PulseAudio Volume Control panel in Playback tab before suspend/resume I could choose the output, say, for Rhythmbox, between my sound card and something called 'LADSPA Plugin Multiband EQ on my card' then after it this choice disappears at all. PulseAudio EQ control panel is still reachable but I believe it operates only EQ configuration not the module itself.

What can be wrong? Is it PulseAudio server which behaves incorrectly or the plugin itself?

By the way, from syslog:

```
Sep  7 11:42:32 music pulseaudio[2496]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: Got POLLNVAL from ALSA  
Sep  7 11:42:32 music pulseaudio[2496]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: Could not recover from POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP with snd_pcm_prepare(): No such device  
Sep  7 11:42:32 music pulseaudio[2496]: [pulseaudio] module-console-kit.c: GetUnixUser() call failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetUnixUser" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session" doesn't exist  
Sep  7 11:42:32  pulseaudio[2496]: last message repeated 2 times
```